# Very slow SELECT from partitioned table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, database-partitioning, postgresql-9.5

I use Postgresql 9.5. The settings are default.

I have split a table into ~7000 partitions. Then I've inserted one row.

When I query `SELECT * FROM "Offer";`, it is running **1,5** seconds.

When I query `SELECT * FROM "Offer" WHERE bid=4793;`, where bid -- partition's constraint (one table per bid), it is running **1** second.

Here is an EXPLAIN ANALYZE for second query:

```
Append  (cost=0.00..12.14 rows=2 width=596) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on "Offer"  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=344) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (bid = 4793)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
  ->  Seq Scan on "Offer-4793"  (cost=0.00..11.12 rows=1 width=848) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: (bid = 4793)
Planning time: 996.243 ms
Execution time: 0.261 ms
```

Why so slow? What can I use to profile it?
I have only one guess -- postgresql does not keep partitioning constrains in RAM and reads them from HDD every time.

Expecting some help!

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to create cascading partitioning (as @jmelesky has written). Results are worse:

```
Append  (cost=0.00..12.24 rows=5 width=848) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on "Offer"  (cost=0.00..1.11 rows=1 width=848) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
    Filter: (bid = 4793)
  ->  Seq Scan on "Offer-ddd-3"  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=848) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
    Filter: (bid = 4793)
  ->  Seq Scan on "Offer-dd-33"  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=848) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)
    Filter: (bid = 4793)
  ->  Seq Scan on "Offer-d-336"  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=848) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)
    Filter: (bid = 4793)
  ->  Seq Scan on "Offer-4793"  (cost=0.00..11.12 rows=1 width=848) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)
    Filter: (bid = 4793)
Planning time: 1449.872 ms
Execution time: 0.354 ms
```

Comment: And `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`?

Comment: Do you have an index on `bid`?

Comment: What's the time for just executing the `EXPLAIN`? The postgres planner doesn't scale to thousands of possible tables very well, and you might just be seeing that.

Comment: @zerkms, I've clarified.

Comment: @gordon-linoff, no, I have not. I've desided, that index improves perfomance inside a table. Every table has only one bid value, so there's no necessity in index

Comment: @jmelesky, the time of the EXPLAIN is about the query time. I've added this info.

Comment: Well, that's it, then. If the planner itself is slow, then there's no easy way to improve that aside from simplifying the query (which, in this case, means having fewer partitions). You can try something like having only 10 partitions, but each one of those is a parent table with 10 partitions, and each one of those is a parent table with 7 partitions -- that *might* make the planner's job easier, but I've never tried it, so can't be certain.

Comment: @jmelesky, nice idea! But it's a little bit harder)

Comment: "*it is running 1,5 seconds*" - no it's **not**. The execution plan clearly shows that executing that statement on the server only take **0.2 milli** seconds (as reported by the `Execution time: 0.261 ms` part). So that' less then a **milli** second. Not sure where the 1.5 seconds come from, but they are definitely not lost  on the server.

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name, planning takes about 1-1,5 seconds. What it does exactly?

Comment: FYI, when I researched this a few years ago (I think I used 9.3), the planner had significantly supralinear performance based on the number of tables/indexes involved. I suspect the relevant code is in backend/optimizer/path if you want to look at it. There's also a constant hard limit to the number of tables that can be involved in a single query (32000, iirc) beyond which the planner will just hang until a sysadmin intervenes.